# Hadoop: How to collect output of Reduce into a Java HashMap

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, similarity, cascading

I'm using Hadoop to compute co-occurrence similarity between words. I have a file that consists of co-occurring word pairs that looks like:

```
a b
a c
b c
b d
```

I'm using a **Graph** based approach that treats words as nodes and co-occurring words have an edge between them. My algorithm needs to compute the degree of all nodes. I've successfully written a `Map-Reduce` job to compute the total degree which outputs the following:

```
a 2
b 3
c 2
d 1
```

Currently, the output is written back to a file but what I want instead is to capture the result into, say, a `java.util.HashMap`. I, then, want to use this `HashMap` in an other `Reduce` job to compute the final similarity.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to capture results of reduce job in memory (`List`, `Map`). If so, how ?
2. Is this the best approach ? If not, How should I deal with this ?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need both the input of your first job en the output of your first job to run the second? In either case it should be possible to simply cascade two jobs. How large is the hashmap expected to be? (you might be able to put it in distributed cache for the second job)

Comment: You are right ! I need both the input of the first job and the output of the first job to run the second job. HashMap may span upto few tens of thousands of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two possibilities: Or you read the data in your map/reduce task from the distributed file system. Or you add it directly to the distributed cache. I just googled distributed cache size, and it can be controlled:

> "The local.cache.size parameter controls the size of the
>   DistributedCache. By default, it’s set to 10 GB."

[Link to cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/sending-files-to-remote-task-nodes-with-hadoop-mapreduce/)

So if you add the output of your first job to the distributed cache of the second you should be fine I think. Tens of thousands of entries are nowhere near the gigabyte range.

Adding a file to the distributed cache goes as follows:

**TO READ** in your mapper:

```
Path[] uris = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
String patternsFile = uris[0].toString();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(patternsFile));
```

**TO ADD** to the DBCache:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(file), job.getConfiguration());
```

while setting up your second job.

Let me know if this does the trick.

Comment: If this answers your question please 'accept as an answer to close'